# How to limit the choice in an NSOpenPanel to a specific filename?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsopenpanel

When showing an NSOpenPanel, is there a way to limit the choice of the file to files which have a certain filename? I know you can limit the file types by setting `openPanel.allowedFileTypes`, but for a specific feature the user needs to select a file which is known to have a certain name (`diallist.csv`).

I know I can check after the panel closes, but it seems more user friendly to me to not let the user choose unacceptable files in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a delegate for the `NSOpenPanel` : https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsopensavepaneldelegate

As delegate you can validate and/or enable certain URLs:

`- (BOOL)panel:(id)sender shouldEnableURL:(NSURL *)url;`
or
`- (BOOL)panel:(id)sender validateURL:(NSURL *)url error:(NSError * _Nullable *)outError;`